# Chaining Background Tasks Alamofire

Tags: ios, networking, alamofire, background-process

I have a question about Alamofire and its behavior with a SessionManager configured for background Tasks. I am using it to upload a video in the background.

**Step I: Uploading Video:**
This part is standard, however, when the upload completes:

**Step II: Completing Upload:**
I need to send a DELETE request to the server letting it know that the video upload is complete. If successful, the response will contain a location header for the newly uploaded video.

**Step III Add Video MetaData:**
With this location I need to PATCH request the video metadata: Title and Description.

So my question is about overriding the Session Manager delegate closures. I can override `sessionDidFinishEventsForBackgroundURLSession` and `taskDidComplete` and when I am completely finished with the background I need to call the system completionHandler that I am storing as a property on the SessionManager... So when/ where should I fire off the DELETE request and then when/where should I fire off the PATCH request?

Should I create 3 different background session configuration identifiers so I can identify them and make sure I chain them in right order? Because obviously I cannot say in the closure: the first time you are called fire off this request, but the second fire off this one? And which closure of the 2 is the right one to finish off the whole process and call the system completionHandler? I'm not sure if this is right because I will be out of sync with the Alamofire upload response handler.

Also I am wondering about the Alamofire response handlers. If the app was in the foreground the whole time? I would simply chain the alamofire requests together using the response handlers? but if the app terminated and is running in the background will these handlers still be around?

Any insight here would be greatly appreciated. I realize there is a lot going on here and Apple eve rate limits background tasks, I'm just wondering if this is possible and if so how to go about it?

Comment: Make it more readable by dividing it into parts with paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I create 3 different background session configuration
>   identifiers so I can identify them and make sure I chain them in right
>   order?

I dont think you will need multiple background sessions just to identify for which request the completion block was called and to chain the next request. You can achieve it with

1. **Asynchronous NSOperation :** 
   You can make use of Asynchronous NSOperations to chain the multiple requests. Add the dependency among the operations and let the iOS handle scheduling and handling the dependencies. Please note : I mentioned **Asynchronous** NSOperation. NSOperations are **Synchronous** by nature.
2. **Promise kit :**
   If Asynchronous NSOperations are way too complicated, you can always use Promise kit. Promise kit will take care of executing the request only after the specific request completes and the whole dependency chain will short circuit if one on the top fails.
3. Simply create a new data task in the completion block of upload task to upload the video. Rather than using the delegate pattern for tasks use completion blocks. That way you dont have to identify for which request the delegate was called, as each task will have its own completion block, you can easily chain them up while writing the code.

> if the app terminated and is running in the background will these
>   handlers still be around?

Am not 100% sure though, but as far as I know, when you schedule the background task (background session), task will continue to execute even if the app is killed.After all, thats why we use background session. So I believe the completion handlers will be executed even if you kill the app.